# Normaloid operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $B(H) $ be the Banach algebra of all bounded linear operators acting on an infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space  $ H $. Let  $ A, B\in B(H) $,  such that

$$ r(A)= \Vert A \Vert,$$
$$ r(B)= \Vert B \Vert .$$
Where $r(A)$ is the specral radius of $A$.

Do we have $$ r(A+B)= \Vert A +B\Vert?$$

Comment: Can you give an example of $H$ and $C\in B(H)$ such that $r(C) <\|C\|$? Then we should only find an $A$ such that both $r(A) = \|A\|$ and $r(A+C) =\|A+C\|$..

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}10&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},\qquad B=\begin{pmatrix}-10&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
You have $\|A\|=\|B\|=10=r(A)=r(B)$. However
$$A+B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix},$$
which has spectral radius $0$ but certainly not norm $0$. This example lives in $\Bbb C^3$, but just extend by $0$ on the orthogonal complement to get it to work on $B(H)$.

Comment: Remark: If you downvote please leave a comment about what can be improved.